# String possible combinations

Tags: combinations

Assume a string of four symbols, for example `s = abcd`
Consider only those strings with exactly one instance of each symbol, such that s=bacd and s=dacb are both valid strings but s=aabc is not. This gives 4! possible combinations.

Now, each symbol can take a value among

```
a = [0, 1]
b = [0, 1, 2, 3]
c = [0, 1]
d = [0, 1, 2]
```

Consequently I may end up having `s=cdab=0112` or `s=abcd=0000` or `s=abdc=1320` etc..

I wish to compute how many combinations (no repetitions) can string s take.

I have written an algorithm that probes all different combinations and discards duplicates, but I would like to understand if a formula can be constructed that returs the same result (not the list of all valid combinatins, but only the number of them).

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you take a lateral step, based on your example

your members are a0,a1,b0,b1,b2,b3 ... d2 which means the possible combinations is 11!

Comment: No, it's not the factorial of 4.

Comment: No, it's not 11! either. Let me give you an example. If I have 3 symbols a=[0] b=[0,1] c=[0,1,2] and s=abc, then possible combinations for s are (000,001,002,010,011,012). For s=acb you have (000,001,010,011,020,021) and so forth. You discard the duplicates and (in this example) are left with 16 combinations (000,001,002,010,011,012,020,021,100,101,102,110,120,200,201,210). I have found an algorithm that runs in O(n!) (in this example 3!), but I was wondering whether O(n) or O(1) is feasible.

Comment: Okay I get you now. so 000 could be abc, bca, cba ... etc. Have to think now, but there must be some relationshion involving the number of letters, and the number of values each letter can be represented by. Interesting, perhaps you might be better moving this to math.overflow

Comment: In your example, you give 020 as one possible combination out of the 16 you came up with.  But, I don't quite understand how that could be a combination since "2" is not in the set of a or b.  "2" is the last element of set c.  So if 020 is a legitimate combination, then that means that you are looking for all permutations of set c including repetitions of any value withing set c.  Is that correct?